# Joining each element of second tuples to the end of each element of the first tuples

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, function-construction, tuples

How can I generate a new tuples by joining each element of tup3 to tup1?
For example joining {0,1,1,1,0,-1} from tup1 and {d,0,1} from tup3 to generate {0,1,1,1,0,-1,d,0,1}

```
tup1 = Tuples@{{0, 1}, {-1, 0, 1}, {-1, 0, 1}, {0, 1}, {-1, 0, 
     1}, {-1, 0, 1}};
tup2 = Tuples[{{0, 1, -1}, {0, 1, -1}}];
tup3 = tup2 /. {a_, b_} :> {d, a, b}
```

Comment: `Join @@@ Tuples[{tup1, tup3}]`?

Comment: @kglr well, that works. Do you have any method to get that directly from tup1 and tup2? 
Above I have to add one more step to add tup3 to add the "d".

Comment: try `Join @@@ Tuples[{tup1, {{d}}, tup2}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tup4a = Join @@@ Tuples[{tup1, tup3}];
tup4a // Short
```

> ```
>  {{0,-1,-1,0,-1,-1,d,0,0},{0,-1,-1,0,-1,-1,d,0,1},<<2912>>,
>   {1,1,1,1,1,1,d,-1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,d,-1,-1}}
> ```

```
tup4b = Distribute[{tup1, tup3}, List, List, List, Join];

tup4a == tup4b
```

> ```
> True
> ```

***"to get that directly from tup1 and tup2"***:

```
tup4c = Join @@@ Tuples[{tup1, {{d}}, tup2}];

tup4a == tup4c
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: well, that looks simple now just apply Join at level 1 but I couldn't think of.